# Loops of count command in Stata

Tags: dataset, stata

Software: Stata

I have two datasets: one of company CEOs (dataset 1) and one of business agreements signed (dataset 2).

Dataset 1 is the following format, sorted by company:

```
company 1, CEO name, start date, end date, etc.  
company 1, CEO name, start date, end date, etc.  
...  
company 2, CEO name, start date, end date, etc.
```

Dataset 2 is the following format, sorted by agreement (each with 2-150 parties):

```
agreement 1, party 1, party 1 accession date, party 2, party 2 accession date. 
agreement 2, party 1, party 1 accession date, party 2, party 2 accession date.
```

I want to write a code that, for each individual CEO, counts the number of agreements signed by the CEO's company in his/her tenure as CEO.

So far I have created a CEO-day dataset with `expand`.

```
gen duration  = enddate - startdate 
expand duration -1 
sort id startdate
by id: gen n = _n -1
gen day = startdate + n
```

Ideally I would proceed with a code like this:

```
collapse (count) agreement, by(id)
```

However, Dataset 2 lists the different parties as different variables. Company 1 is not always "party 1", sometimes it may be "party 150". Also, each party may have different accession dates. I need a loop that "scans" Dataset 2 for agreements where company 1 acceeded to the agreement as one of the parties with an accession date located within the period CEO 1 of company 1 was CEO of company 1.

What should I do? Do I need to create a loop?

Answer (score 0):

A loop is not strictly necessary. You can try using `reshape` and `joinby`:

```
clear
set more off

*----- example data -----

// ceo data set
input ///
firm str15(ceo startd endd)
1 "pete" "01/04/1999" "05/12/2010"
1 "bill" "06/12/2010" "12/01/2011"
1 "lisa" "13/01/2011" "15/06/2014"
2 "mary" "01/04/1999" "05/12/2010"
2 "hank" "06/12/2010" "12/01/2011"
2 "mary" "13/01/2011" "15/06/2014"
3 "bob" "01/04/1999" "05/12/2010"
3 "john" "06/12/2010" "12/01/2011"
end

gen double startd2 = date(startd, "DMY")
gen double endd2 = date(endd, "DMY")
format %td startd2 endd2
drop startd endd

tempfile ceo
save "`ceo'"

clear

// agreement data set
input ///
agree party1 str15 p1acc party2 str15 p2acc
1 2 "09/12/2010" 3 "10/01/2011"
2 1 "05/06/1999" 2 "17/01/2011"
3 1 "06/06/1999" 3 "05/04/1999"
4 2 "07/01/2011" . ""
5 2 "08/01/2011" . ""
end

gen double p1accn = date(p1acc, "DMY")
gen double p2accn = date(p2acc, "DMY")
format %td p?accn
drop p?acc

*----- what you want -----

// reshape
gen i = _n
reshape long party p@accn, i(i)

rename (party paccn) (firm date)

order firm agree date
sort firm agree
drop i _j

// joinby
joinby firm using "`ceo'"

// find under which ceo, agreement was signed
gen tag = inrange(date, startd2, endd2)

list, sepby(firm)

// count
keep if tag
collapse (count) agreenum=tag, by(ceo firm)

list
```

A potential pitfall is `joinby` creating so many observations, you run out of memory.

See `help datetime` if you have no experience with dates in Stata.

(Notice how I set up example data for your problem. Providing it helps others, help you.)

Comment: Thanks!

1) In the agreement data set, every agreement has at least a party 1 and 2. However, after running `gen double p1accn = date(p1acc, "DMY")` and `format %td p1accn`, some dates are reported as missing. Dates such as 30-Mar-45 and 1/25/1949 are reported as missing. 8/3/1949 is not reported as missing. 

2) Some dates such as 2/9/29, which refers to a 1929 agreement, is reported as the year 2029. Do you know of a solution to this?

3) With regard to the code, the output only included CEOs that signed agreements. Is there any part of the code that excludes CEOs that signed no agreements?

Comment: Regarding the date issues, if the the _mask_, i.e. `"DMY"`, used in the `date()` function is inconsistent with the date string, you'll get missings. For example, the string `1/25/1949` will be missing because there is no such thing as a month 25 in a calendar year. If your date variable has multiple-form date strings, you need to fix that first. See `help datetime` and the relevant manual entries. One strategy is to `generate` multiple variables, one for each form, and then combine into a final variable.

Comment: CEOs that do not sign are dropped when `keep if tag` is executed.